# iOS CoreMotion.MotionThread EXC_BAD_ACCESS is thrown after stopDeviceMotionUpdates() is called

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, exc-bad-access, core-motion

I have a view controller that uses CoreMotion to monitor the device's Attitude.

Here is the handler that is used in the call to startDeviceMotionUpdates():

```
/**
     * Receives device motion updates from Core Motion and uses the attitude of the device to update
     * the position of the attitude tracker inside the bubble level view.
     */
    private func handleAttitude(deviceMotion: CMDeviceMotion?, error: Error?) {
        guard let attitude = deviceMotion?.attitude else {
            GLog.Error(message: "Could not get device attitude.")
            return
        }
        
        // Calculate the current attitude vector
        let roll = attitude.roll
        let pitch = attitude.pitch - optimalAngle
        let magnitude = sqrt(roll * roll + pitch * pitch)
        
        // Drawing can only happen on the main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            [weak self] in
            
            guard let weakSelf = self else {
                GLog.Log("could not get weak self")
                return
            }
            // Move the bubble in the attitude tracker to match the current attitude
            weakSelf.bubblePosX.constant = CGFloat(roll * weakSelf.attitudeScalar)
            weakSelf.bubblePosY.constant = CGFloat(pitch * weakSelf.attitudeScalar)
            
            // Set the border color based on the current attitude.
            if magnitude < weakSelf.yellowThreshold {
                weakSelf.attitudeView.layer.borderColor = weakSelf.green.cgColor
            } else if magnitude < weakSelf.redThreshold {
                weakSelf.attitudeView.layer.borderColor = weakSelf.yellow.cgColor
            } else {
                weakSelf.attitudeView.layer.borderColor = weakSelf.red.cgColor
            }
            
            // Do the actual drawing
            weakSelf.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

I added [weak self] to see if it would fix things, but it has not. This crash is not easy to reproduce.

When I am done the with VC that uses CoreMotion, I call stopDeviceMotionUpdates() in the VC's viewWillDisappear() method. This VC is the only class in the app that imports CoreMotion.

However, when I arrive in the next VC, occasionally I see EXC_BAD_ACCESS getting thrown on a co m.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread.

[image: MotionThread backtrace]

Anybody know why CoreMotion would spawn a thread after the VC that used it has been dismissed? I've verified that the VC is no longer in memory when the crash happens. And yes, the two VCs I'm dealing with are presented modally.

I've examined the memory graph, and when the crash happens, these CoreMotion objects are being reported:

[image]

And:

[image]

I don't know if those objects should still be in memory after the instance of the CoreMotionManager has been deallocated or not. According to the memory graph, there is no instance of CoreMotionManager in memory.

The VC that imports CoreMotion also imports ARKit. Not sure if some crazy interaction between CoreMotion and ARKit is the problem.

There does seem to be something going on between the main thread and the MotionThread(14):

[image: expanded stack trace]

I'm not sure what to make of the main thread stack trace.

Sometimes when the CoreMotion VC is dismissed, I've noticed that there is a lag in the memory it uses getting released. The release always happens eventually.

Thanks to anybody who can help!

Answer (score 2):

We have a ARSCNView member. We were not calling sceneView.session.pause() when we dismissed the VC that used the sceneView member. One line of code. That was it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing the function `handleAttitude` direct to `startDeviceMotionUpdates`

as in `startDeviceMotionUpdates(to:someQueue, withHandler:handleAttitude)`

That will set up a retain cycle between your VC and `CMMotionManager`

Try

```
singletonMM.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to:someQueue) { [weak self] motion,error in
    self?.handleAttitude(motion,error)
}
```

To prevent a strong ref to your VC.

Comment: That is so obvious! I did not even notice it! Not a single handler in the VC is using weak self in any of the methods that take handlers. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Well, that was not the fix. I took over this app from two other devs, and there were dozens of places in the code where closures were being used without using [weak self].  So I went and added [weak self] to all of the closures, but the crash is still happening.

Comment: I read somewhere that your app should only use one instance of CMMotionManager. Which is true of my app. But ARKit uses CoreMotion. And I'm using ARKit and a CMMotionManager at the same time in my app. I wonder if the two are conflicting somehow.

Comment: Not all closures need to be weakified. Weakifying ALL closures is voodoo  level programming :-)  My suggestion related specifically to passing a function as a closure. The docs do say to have just one CMMotionManager per app but I interpret that as just 1 that the app owns. If ARKit owns one too that shouldn’t be an issue. You are creating the CMMM just once and using it for the lifetime of your app?

Comment: The CMMM is used for the lifetime of the VC, which also uses ARKit. Once this VC is dismissed stopDeviceMotionUpdates() is called in viewWillDisappear(). The VC that is presented afterwards uses SceneKit to display data captured using ARKit in the previous VC. Thanks again for helping!